# Tizen native service app to check if another app is running

Tags: service, native, tizen

In Samsung gear S3, I want to develop a Tizen native service application which continously checks if a web application is running or not and launches the web application if its not running.
By continously, I mean it can be either checking every minute or adding an event listener (for state change of application).

I wanted to do this because my web application is getting terminated after some time (may be after a day or so) but I want it to run always in background.

Right now,I was able to launch the web application from service application with the following code.

```
app_control_h app_control;
int ret = APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE;
ret = app_control_create(&app_control);

if (ret != APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE)
   dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "app_control_create() is failed. err = %d", ret);

ret = app_control_set_operation(app_control, APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_VIEW);

if (ret != APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE)
   dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "app_control_set_operation() is failed. err = %d", ret);

app_control_set_app_id(app_control, "08CCMUEFHN.ROAMMprompt");

ret = app_control_send_launch_request(app_control, NULL, NULL);
if (ret != APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE)
   dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "app_control_send_launch_request() is failed. err = %d", ret);
```

Please help me in developing code to continuously check if my web application is running or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of Developing additional Native Service application, Your Web application can itself Do your desired task.**

Tizen **Alarm API** enables you to schedule an application to be run at a specific time. When an alarm is triggered, the application is launched (unless it is already running).

Register a repetitive alarm using Web Alarm API that would Launch the Web app itself after your desired time frame.

```
var appId = "com.samsung.clocksetting"; 
// Your desired appId, in this case 'settings' app

var alarmR = new tizen.AlarmRelative(2* tizen.alarm.PERIOD_MINUTE, 30 * tizen.alarm.PERIOD_MINUTE);
// Set an alarm in system that would trigger after 2 minutes and then every 30 minitues  

tizen.alarm.add(alarmR, appId);
```

Add 'alarm' **privilege** in your config.xml. Check out these Links for details implementation:

[Tizen Web Alarm Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/alarm)

[Tizen Web Alarm API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/alarm.html#AlarmRelative)

Comment: Thank you so much. Its simple and brilliant. I have one more question. My application is launched from a notification which pops up four times a day. Is there a way to know that the app is launched from notification but not by clicking on the app icon in the watch face.

Comment: I'm curious about if you guys contributed to that forum as well. Both questions and answers are same. Can anyone tell me how?